# How to add simple product to grouped product as Associated products?

Tags: php, magento, product

I have grouped product with the name Group1. And also I have category with the same name(Group1).
I have several simple product under the Group1 category. How to add these products under this category only as Associated product to grouped product programmatically?

**EDIT**

I got a product collection under the category named as Group1 by

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection') 
                      ->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

Now i want to add these products to the Grouped product as Associated product

If anybody know, please help me guys

Comment: If i knew, then why am i post my question here? @BGS

Comment: What you try so far..

Comment: @BGS I have edit my question. Please refer

Answer (score 0):

foreach ($productarr as $product) {

```
       $products_links = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link_api');
        $products_links->assign ("grouped",$groupId,$product); 
}
```

// here $productarr  is array of ids of simple product 
$groupId is id of group product